# Downloading Images in order of url's - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, semaphore

I have 10 urls in an array and when 4 of them downloaded I need to display them. Im using Semaphores and groups to implement . But looks like im hitting deadlock. Not sure how to proceed. Please advice how I can

Simulating same in playground:

```swift
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let group = DispatchGroup()
let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive)
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 4)
var nums: [Int] = []
for i in 1...10 {
    
    group.enter()
    semaphore.wait()
    queue.async(group: group) {
        print("Downloading image \(i)")
        // Simulate a network wait
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 3)
        nums.append(i)
        print("Hola image \(i)")
        if nums.count == 4 {
            print("4 downloaded")
            semaphore.signal()
            group.leave()
        }
    }
    if nums.count == 4 {
        break
    }
}

group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
    print(nums)
}
```

I get this in o/p console

```
> Downloading image 1
> Downloading image 2
> Downloading image 3
> Downloading image 4
```

> Semaphores(41269,0x70000ade5000) malloc: *** error for object 0x1077d4750: pointer being freed was not allocated
>
> Semaphores(41269,0x70000ade5000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

I'm expecting to print [1,2,3,4] in order

I know im trying to access a shared resource in async but not sure how I can fix this. Please advice

Also How can I use this with semaphore's if I want to download 4,4,2 tasks at a time so it display [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] in my ouput

Comment: Semaphores to manipulate asynchronous tasks are awful. If you want to download the images in oder look for an asynchronous `Operation` on a serial `OperationQueue` and observe the number of running operations with KVO.

Answer (score 3):

Your title says “Downloading Images in order of url’s”, but your code snippet is not attempting to do that. It appears to be attempting to use semaphores to constrain the download to four images at a time, but it won’t guarantee that they’ll be in order.

It is commendable that this code snippet isn’t attempting to download them in order, sequentially, one after another, because that would impose a huge performance penalty. It is also good that this code snippet is constraining this degree of concurrency to something reasonable, thereby avoiding exhausting worker threads or causing some of the latter requests to timeout. So, the idea of using semaphore to allow concurrent image download, but constrain it to four at a time, is a fine approach; we only need to sort the results at the end if you want them in order.

But before we get to that, let’s tackle a bunch of problems in the supplied code snippet:

1. You are calling `group.enter()` and `semaphore.wait()` for every iteration (which is correct), but `group.leave()` and `semaphore.signal()` only when `i` is `4` (which is not correct). You want to `leave` and `signal` for every iteration.

   Obviously, that `break` call is not needed, either.

   So, to fix this “do four at a time” process, one can simplify this code:

   ```
   let group = DispatchGroup()
   let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive)
   let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 4)

   var nums: [Int] = []

   for i in 1...10 {
       group.enter()
       semaphore.wait()

       queue.async() {                      // NB: the `group` parameter is not needed
           print("Downloading image \(i)")
           // Simulate a network wait
           Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 3)
           nums.append(i)
           print("Hola image \(i)")

           semaphore.signal()
           group.leave()
       }
   }

   group.notify(queue: .main) {
       print(nums)
   }
   ```

   That will download four images at a time and will call your `group.notify` closure when they’re all done.
2. While the above fixes the semaphore and group logic, there is yet another problem lurking in the above code snippet. It is updating that `nums` array from multiple background threads, but `Array` is not thread-safe. So you should synchronize those updates to that array. An easy way to achieve this is to dispatch that update back to the main thread. (Any serial queue would have been fine, but the main thread works fine for this purpose.)

   Also, since one should never call `wait` on the main queue, so I’d suggest that you explicitly dispatch this entire `for` loop to a background thread:

   ```
   DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
       let group = DispatchGroup()
       let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive)
       let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 4)
       var nums: [Int] = []

       for i in 1...10 {
           group.enter()
           semaphore.wait()

           queue.async() {
               print("Downloading image \(i)")
               // Simulate a network wait
               Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 3)
               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   nums.append(i)
                   print("Hola image \(i)")
               }

               semaphore.signal()
               group.leave()
           }
       }

       group.notify(queue: .main) {
           print(nums)
       }
   }
   ```

   That is now the correct “do four at a time and let me know when it’s done.”

---

OK, now that we’re downloading all of the images properly, let’s figure out how to sort the results. Frankly, I think it’s easier to follow what’s going on if we imagine that we have some image download method, like so, that downloads a particular image:

```
func download(_ url: URL, completion: @escaping (Result<UIImage, Error>) -> Void) { ... }
```

Then the routine to (a) download the images, no more than four at a time; and (b) return the results back in order, might look like:

```
func downloadAllImages(_ urls: [URL], completion: @escaping ([UIImage]) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 4)
        var imageDictionary: [URL: UIImage] = [:]

        // download the images

        for url in urls {
            group.enter()
            semaphore.wait()

            self.download(url) { result in
                defer {
                    semaphore.signal()
                    group.leave()
                }

                switch result {
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)

                case .success(let image):
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        imageDictionary[url] = image
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // now sort the results

        group.notify(queue: .main) {
            completion(urls.compactMap { imageDictionary[$0] })
        }
    }
}
```

And you’d call it like so:

```
downloadAllImages(urls) { images in
    self.images = images
    self.updateUI()        // do whatever you want to trigger the update of the UI
}
```

---

FWIW, the “download single image” routine might look like:

```
enum DownloadError: Error {
    case notImage
    case invalidStatusCode(URLResponse)
}

func download(_ url: URL, completion: @escaping (Result<UIImage, Error>) -> Void) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, error == nil else {
            completion(.failure(error!))
            return
        }

        guard 200..<300 ~= response.statusCode else {
            completion(.failure(DownloadError.invalidStatusCode(response)))
            return
        }

        guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
            completion(.failure(DownloadError.notImage))
            return
        }

        completion(.success(image))
    }
}
```

And this is using the Swift 5 `Result` enumeration. If you’re using an earlier version of Swift, you can define a simple rendition of this enum yourself:

```
enum Result<Success, Failure> {
    case success(Success)
    case failure(Failure)
}
```

---

Finally, it’s worth noting a few other alternatives:

1. Wrap your network request in asynchronous `Operation` subclass and add them to an operation queue whose `maxConcurrentOperationCount` is set to 4. If you’re interested in this approach, I can supply some references.
2. Use an image downloading library like [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher).
3. Instead of manual downloading of all the images, use the `UIImageView` extension (such as provided by Kingfisher) and completely abandon the “download all images” process at all, and move to a pattern where you simply instruct your image views to asynchronously retrieve the images in either a just-in-time manner (or prefetching).